# Updating shortest path tree

Tags: graph, tree, dijkstra, updating

Assume we are given a weighted, connected, directed graph G, a vertex s and the shortest path tree for s. So we already know all the shortest distances from s to every other vertex in the graph.

Now the following happens, we add an edge to the graph.

Is there an efficient way to get the new shortest path tree?
How can I calculate the new shortest path tree by encountering the old one?